# SQL statement to insert repetitive data

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

current situation is to add below value of `A01`, `B03`, `Z11` and `X21` in repetitive way in field `code` for 400 hundreds row of data in table `BabyCode`.

[image: Current table - without value in 'Code" column]

Above is current table - without value in 'Code" column

[image: To be updated table - repetitive value is added in 'Code' column]

Above is to be updated table - repetitive value is added in 'Code' column

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please clarify your post so others can help you

Comment: i want make a milk in kitchen , someone can help me please? can you share your code , and what have you tried. and your table shema ..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO BabyCode
SELECT Codes.Code
FROM
(
  SELECT id
  FROM
  (
  SELECT t3.digit * 100 + t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1 AS id
  FROM         TEMP AS t1
    CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
    CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t3
  ) t
  WHERE id <= 400
) t,
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A01' AS Code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B03'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Z11' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'X21'
) codes;
```

But you will need to define a temp table, to use as an anchor table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (Digit int);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bda47/1)

This will insert 400 hundred rows of the values `A01`, `B03`, `Z11`, and `X21`, into the `code` column in the table `BabyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the four values into a virtual table identical to that used in @Mahmoud Gamal's answer, and, if the ID values in your table start at 1 and are sequential (have neither gaps nor duplicates), you could use the following method to join to the virtual table and update the target's `Code` column:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A01' AS Code
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'B03'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Z11' 
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'X21'
) x
ON (t.ID - 1) MOD 4 + 1 = x.ID
SET t.Code = x.Code
;
```

Otherwise you could use variables to assign `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` sequentially to every row of your table, then you would be able join to the virtual table using those values:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, @rnk := CASE WHEN @rnk = 4 THEN 0 ELSE @rnk END + 1 AS rnk
  FROM YourTable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0) x
  ORDER BY ID
) r ON t.ID = r.ID
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A01' AS Code
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'B03'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Z11' 
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'X21'
) x
ON r.rnk = x.ID
SET t.Code = x.Code
;
```

Both queries can be played with at SQL Fiddle:

- [Method 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c819/1)
- [Method 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/910db/1)